# videoconferencing/audio-only-conferencing on LAN

Tags: linux, lan

The given scenario is an office-building with several floors. Using linux servers and linux clients it is necessary to create a system for videoconferencing or if not possible then audio-only conferencing within the building only (which is connected by a single local network).

This means a self-hosted hub application with linux client applications.

Does the software for this exist?

Answer (score 1):

I understood that it's not exactly what are you looking for. There is TrueConf Server (free) on-premises solution which is bundled with Linux video conferencing app. However server part of it should be deployed on Windows, dedicated or virtual on Xen doesn't matter, within your LAN. http://trueconf.com/products/apps/linux.html

Comment: Thank you! I have looked at this. However a windows server does not exactly suit my needs. It is simply to heavy on resources and the cost is outrageous :-)

Cheers,